# attempt to index global widget ( a nil value )

Tags: lua, coronasdk

When ever I run this code I get a error that says

> attempt to index global `widget` (a `nil` value)

```
local inc = 0.0
local levelUpBar, player
levelUpBar = widget.newProgressView {
   left = display.contentWidth*0.5-100,
   top = 300,
   width = 200,
   isAnimated = true }
levelUpBar:setProgress( 0 )  


local function playerHit(event)
    if(event.phase == "began") then
        inc = inc + 0.2
        if(inc > 1) then
            print('level up!')
        else
            levelUpBar:setProgress( inc )
        end
    end
end

player = display.newCircle(0,0,75)
player.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
player.y = 200
player:setFillColor(0,200,0)
player:addEventListener("touch", playerHit)
```

Comment: Where/How are you running this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
local widget = require("widget");
```

at the top of code